Using python AST to traverse code and extract return statements
I have a python script that I am trying to "decode" as it were so that I can cast it as an xml, but for this exercise I am just trying to get my head around using ast.walk() and how best to get info out of it. Below is a very simple function that I wrote to simple_if.py and what I am trying to do is extract the function name and the return statements as a list in order.
def if_else(abc):
    if abc > 0:
        return "Hello"
    elif abc < 0:
        return "Goodbye"
    return "Neither Hello Nor Goodbye"

When I put the above into the file and run the below ast functions on it like so
with open("simple_if.py", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as ast_tree_walker
    tree = ast.parse(ast_tree_walker.read())

expList = []
counter = 0

for node in ast.walk(tree):
    print(node)
    if isInstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) and counter == 0:
        expList.append(node.__dict__["name"]
        counter = 1 # this adds the functiona name if_else to the list 
    print(node.__dict__)

The above would give a terminal output of nodes, dicts, and args, but the only thing I have been able to accomplish is extracting the function name since it is the first non-Module node in the tree. I know I am dumping everything that I "want" but its not clear to me how I should keep track of the ordering for instance "Neither Hello Nor Goodbye" would appear before either of "Hello" or "Goodbye" and although I assume that is because in terms of a tree the final return is on the same level as the if statement it is not clear to me how I can maintain order (if at all).  Basically does anyone know how I could return a list of ["if_else", "Hello", "Goodbye", "Neither Hello Nor Goodbye"]? On some level I feel this is a fools errand, but in the pursuit of knowledge I am wondering how to go about this.
Nuanced question the above prints out types of:
<ast.Module object at (random token string that I won't write)>, <ast.FunctionDef object at >, <ast.If object at >, <ast.Return object at >... 

When I come across a "<ast.If object at >" should I step into the 'body' key directly or somehow just wait till that child node gets visited and then extract the info?
#children of ast.If
{'test': <ast.Compare object at>, 'body" <ast.Return object at >, 'orelse': [<ast.If object at>, 'lineno':2, 'col_offset':7}


The documentation of ast.walk() says the nodes are not in any particular order.

The order of the three returns isn't meaningful, anyway - they could be written in any order whatsoever, just by changing the conditions in the if and elif.

Jason, I agree in the above example I could have moved the if/else/returns to give a different order, but I do wish to maintain the order by going "straight" down (dfs) and I was confused by the documentation that ast.walk() implied that nodes will be in random order, but as the below answer correctly points out the implementation is bfs (and also points me to applying dfs). I think a lot of my confusion was in the documentation that was incorrectly stated.

Although the documentation claims that ast.walk generates nodes "in no specified order" and even misleadingly characterizes its behavior as "Recursively yield all descendant nodes...", a quick look at the source code reveals that it really performs a simple breadth-first traversal by iteratively yielding child nodes in a queue:
def walk(node):
    """
    Recursively yield all descendant nodes in the tree starting at *node*
    (including *node* itself), in no specified order.  This is useful if you
    only want to modify nodes in place and don't care about the context.
    """
    from collections import deque
    todo = deque([node])
    while todo:
        node = todo.popleft()
        todo.extend(iter_child_nodes(node))
        yield node

So the node for return "Neither Hello Nor Goodbye" is yielded before the node for return "Hello" because the former is an immediate child of def if_else(...) while the latter is a child of its child.
To produce the nodes in your desired depth-first order you can write your own recursive node traversal function instead:
import ast

def dfs_walk(node):
    yield node
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        yield from dfs_walk(child)

so that:
tree = ast.parse('''\
def if_else(abc):
    if abc > 0:
        return "Hello"
    elif abc < 0:
        return "Goodbye"
    return "Neither Hello Nor Goodbye"
''')

expList = []
for node in dfs_walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        expList.append(node.name)
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Return):
        expList.append(node.value.value)
print(expList)

outputs:
['if_else', 'Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Neither Hello Nor Goodbye']

Demo here

"Walk" is not needed (but an ast.Visitor Class)
import ast

class MyVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.return_string = []
    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Return):
            self.return_string.append(ast.unparse(node))
            super().generic_visit(node)
        else:
            super().generic_visit(node)

code ='''\
def if_else(abc):
    if abc > 0:
        return "Hello"
    elif abc < 0:
        return "Goodbye"
    return "Neither Hello Nor Goodbye"
'''



tree = ast.parse(code)
vis = MyVisitor()
vis.visit(tree)

Output:
return 'Hello'
return 'Goodbye'
return 'Neither Hello Nor Goodbye'

